# If $\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}=k\sec x$, then k is?

Tags: trigonometry

Q: If $\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}=k\sec x$, then k is?

A: From $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}=k\sec x$,

$\implies \sqrt{\frac{(1+\sin x)^2}{1-\sin^2x}}=k\sec x$

$\implies \pm\frac{(1+\sin x)}{\cos x}=k\sec x$

From inequality $\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi$, we know that x lies in the second quadrant, thus $\cos x$ is negative.

$\therefore -\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos s}=k\sec x$

$\implies -(1+\sin x)=k$

How can I now extract $x$ from these information? The given answer is $k=-1$, without knowing x, I don't see any way of concluding $k$ from the given data.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The given answer is wrong.

Comment: I see. Does that mean $-1-\sin x$ is the final answer? Also can you explain a bit more as to why the answer ($-1$) is wrong? There are other similar questions and they all have some constant for an answer. I was hoping to get to them by understanding this.

Comment: I am guessing the problem has the requirement that $k$ is an integer.

Comment: @dezdichado No such information is given.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original answer

$$ -1 - k = \sin(x)$$

The range of sin(x) on this domain is $(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$:

$$ 0 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$$

Sub the expression:

$$ 0 \leq -1 -k \leq 1$$

Or,

$$ 1 \leq -k \leq 2$$

Or,

$$ -1 \geq k \geq -2$$

So in the whole set above, only legal value is $k=-1$ [ This is actually wrong, indeed $k \in (-1,-2)$

#### Note

For keeping the square root as positive,

$$ \frac{1+ \sin x}{1- \sin x} \geq 0 $$

Or,

$$ 1+ \sin x \geq 0$$

$$ \sin(x) \geq -1$$

Sub exp for sin in terms of k

$$ -1 - k \geq -1 $$

Or,

$$ 0 \geq k$$

$(-1, \infty)$ is the domain

IF you were doing the problem correctly then you would take intersection of allowed domain of square root with the domain of x which is given because at some point it may turn out funct is undefined

---

After thinking about it somewhere without specifying 'x' basically they are saying two functions which match for the whole domain but I don't think there exists a scaling factor 'k' for which that is possible. I made a graph of it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xk8brduazy)

Comment: why does $-1\geq k\geq -2$ imply $k = -1 $ ?

Comment: Actually the same question ^ Selected this as an answer prematurely.

Comment: Good catch, I should have been more careful